# PostalCode Spring Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am new on Spring Framework and I could need some help. 
I am trying to validate data for a city. One of the attributes is the postal code. However, this *postalCode* must be unique within the country the city is located.

So far, I have validated whether this field is empty, and if it exceeds the limited characters, however, I did not validate the *postalCode*.

So far, I am using *cityRepository* to find a city and get its *postalCode* and then I am trying to check if it does not equal to any *postalCode* in the list of countries.

This is my code:

```
 // City postal code validation
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(city.getPostalCode())) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "required");
    } else if (city.getPostalCode().length() > ValidatorConfig.STRING_LENGTH) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "Allowed length is exceeded");
    } else if (cityRepository.findOne(QCity.city.postalCode.eq(city.getPostalCode())) &&
        (countryRepository.findAll(QCountry.country.cities.contains(city.getPostalCode())))) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "Postal Code exists in this country");
    }
```

Can anyone help me find a lead on this matter?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why you should test if postal code is unique in the cityRepository? I think you should trust in the cityRepository and assume that there are not wrong data within it.
The check you should do is the presence of postalCode in the city repository:

```
// City postal code validation
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(city.getPostalCode())) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "required");
    } else if (city.getPostalCode().length() > ValidatorConfig.STRING_LENGTH) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "Allowed length is exceeded");
    } else if (!cityRepository.findOne(QCity.city.postalCode.eq(city.getPostalCode()))) {
        errors.reject("postalCode", "No postal code found");
    }
```

Anyway, I suggest you to improve your question because it's not really clear what is the matter.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. However, I need to check if this postal code is present in any other city, within the same country. I hope i was more clear.